# How can I display GUI while testing PyQt5 app with pytest-qt?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, pytest

I am new to `PyQt`, but I am going to use `pytest` with `pytest-qt` plugin to test my `PyQt5` application. I had some GUI testing experience in Java with `SWTBot` and `RCPTT`, where I could see what happens with controls and whole GUI during the test in real-time. I'd like to have such behavior with my new python tools, but it seems that `pytest-qt` tests GUI in some background way. All code works as I expect, but during testing I can't see the GUI. The code is simple as in tutorials:

```
from tests.test import MyApp
from time import sleep
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


def test_myapp(qtbot):
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MyApp()
    # window.show()
    # app.exec_()
    qtbot.addWidget(window)
    qtbot.mouseClick(window.buttonBox.buttons()[0], Qt.LeftButton)
    sleep(5)
    assert window.label.text() == 'accept'
```

If I uncomment the `window.show()` line (they do so in the [tutorial](http://pytest-qt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)), I can see a strange window, that contains frozen background:

[image: strange window]

I suppose that it is theoretically possible to show the interface because I know that PyQt5 works from the python shell ([more](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/python_shell.html#using-pyqt4-from-the-python-shell)):

> you can, for example, create widgets from the Python shell prompt, interact with them, and still being able to enter other Python commands

But I don't know how to achieve it with pytest-qt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code works as I asked, it shows the interface properly. The key thing is `qtbot.waitForWindowShown(window)` line.

```
from tests.test import MyApp
from time import sleep
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


def test_myapp(qtbot):
    window = MyApp()
    qtbot.addWidget(window)
    window.show()
    qtbot.waitForWindowShown(window)
    sleep(3)
    qtbot.mouseClick(window.buttonBox.buttons()[0], Qt.LeftButton)
    assert window.label.text() == 'accept'
    qtbot.stopForInteraction()
```

Comment: This answer led me to the right place (thank you!), so I'll make a note that as of 2022 `waitForWindowShown` is deprecated ("underlying method was obsoleted in Qt 5 and removed in Qt6"), in favor of `waitExposed`.  The latter should be used as a context manager so the format is a bit different, but it works just as well (at least for me).